# Why the power supplies limit the amperage?

Tags: basic

I'm just learning electronics, and I can't understand something:
If the amperes don't matter in terms of burning the circuit, only voltage, why do phone charges for example have a low current capability?

I understood from the various explanations I've read, I've read that it's okay to use a power supply with higher ampere rating, but not with different voltage. If the ampere rating is the maximum that device can supply, it only consumes what it needs, right?

Comment: Who told you that "amperes don't matter in terms of burning the circuit"?

Comment: Because larger power supplies cost more money, and usb devices only need 1 or 2 Amps max

Comment: @SérgioCamilo, please take your comment, starting with "I understood from the..." and *edit the question* to include it.

Answer (score 5):

Three things:

- Current does matter in burning up the circuit.
- Yes, for a given load that expects a constant voltage, you can attach a supply with a higher current capability* but the same voltage output, and everything works fine.
- The **supply** can only give so much power (i.e., only so much current times voltage).  So if I try to draw one amp from a wall-wart that's only good for a quarter of an amp, then the wall-wart will either quietly shut down, or it'll burn up.

So the rule for *most supply and load combinations* is that you need to select a supply voltage that is within the range that the load can accept (or exactly on, by preference), and you need to select a supply current *capability* that is the same as, or greater than, the load's rated current draw.

* With modern wall-warts and supplies.  Confusingly, older wall-warts would actually supply higher voltage if you asked less current of them.

Answer (score 1):

If by "Burning the circuit" you mean "heating up the circuit", the heating is actually directly related to the current. More current = more heat. The current is determined by the device (the "load"), not the voltage source.

If by "burning" you mean "powering", that is running the device as it's supposed to, the power supply needs to be able to provide equal or more current than the device wants to consume. A device such as a mobile phone can only consume 1-2 A of current, hence a bigger charger with higher current rating would be unnecessarily costly.

Achieving faster battery charging speed comes with a number of problems, such as how much current the battery can accept and how much current the cables safely can conduct.

Answer (score 0):

Phone batteries can't charge at infinite current. Cables and connectors can't handle infinite current either. Therefore you only need about 1-2 amp charger for your phone. If it tries to draw much more than that it may be broken and charger shuts down so the phone or cable does not burn. Phone will take only the current it needs, even if the charger can provide more, like for charging two phones at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

One of the first things to understand is that there are constant voltage supplies, and constant current supplies.

As it turns out, most supplies are constant voltage supplies.

For constant voltage supplies, the voltage rating is actually what the supply put outs, while the current rating is the maximum capability. Therefore, you don't want the supply to exceed the voltage rating of your load.

For constant current supplies, it is the opposite. The current is what the supply actually put outs, and the voltage is the capability of the supply. The output voltage just ends up being whatever it needs (within the limits of the supply) to push that current through the load. In this case, you do not want the current rating to exceed load's current rating.